# Vercel deployment failure

Tags: reactjs, deployment, vercel

i was trying to publish my website via Vercel but somehow i couldn't...
I have the api url and token in index.js in consts folder.
I've tried to put api info in the .env file but i couldn't do that either.

Here is my files and the Vercel's error

I would be really happy if i use some help. Thank you.

[My files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrfnM.png)

[What vercel says](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBNq3.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep all your .js files inside src folder.
Looking at your problem ,it looks like your index.js falls outside src folder. Try placing it directly in your src folder like your App.js, it should work fine.
Also, Run `npm run build` in your VS Code terminal before deploying it.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I installed using "npm install @tippy.js/react" command.
I installed it again using the command "npm i @tippy.js/react" and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ESlint, make sure to add this to next.config.js:

```
  eslint: {
    // Warning: This allows production builds to successfully complete even if
    // your project has ESLint errors.
    ignoreDuringBuilds: true,
  },
```